# Problems with SignalR using NuGet

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am having a problem setting up a simple test project for SignalR.

I installed **SignalR** in `VS WD Express 2010` using `NuGet`, but when I try to run my site I get the following Asp.Net error page. (It looks like all assemblies are added correctly by NuGet)

Anyone seen this before?

```
Could not load type 'SignalR.PersistentConnection' from assembly 'SignalR

[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SignalR.PersistentConnection' from assembly 'SignalR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetBootstrapper.Initialize() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetBootstrapper threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load type 'SignalR.PersistentConnection' from assembly 'SignalR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +423
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetBootstrapper threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load type 'SignalR.PersistentConnection' from assembly 'SignalR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258
```

Comment: This is happening to me and the name of my project is NOT SignalR

Comment: This wouldn't happen now anyways the dll has been renamed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The name of your project is SignalR, change it.

Comment: Why did I name my project SignalR? Duhhh... :D

Comment: Damn it I have been pulling my hair for one hour.